# Filter Items by title with regex

Tags: podio

I'm trying to filter items for a specific App. The problem that I have is that I would like to filter as I would with regular expressions and so

```
"filters": {
  "title": "item"
}
```

Would return "First Item, Second Item, ..." for all the items that match the keyword "item". Otherwise, how can I search for a specific part of a title like: "A1B2C New Company Project" where I would type the unique part being "A1B2C" and get that item?

I'm using the Podio-js library.

Comment: Podio filters does not support regular expressions. If you want to search for unique strings - you can do just that with the Search API : https://developers.podio.com/doc/search/search-in-space-22479

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out tonight. It seems like it could work for all if not most of my use cases.